# PySpice module used in Python Script. How do I convert it to .EXE?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

"PySpice is a Python module which interface Python to the Ngspice and Xyce circuit simulators."

When I try to convert my Python script using Pyinstaller, I get an executable file which I can open but does nothing and sometimes closes on its own.

I figured this has something to do with the PySpice module I am using. Thank you.

Comment: did you run in console/terminal to see error messages?

Comment: Here is the error I received. https://imgur.com/a/YlvReXf

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller does not automatically copy the logging.yaml file into final executable.

You'd have to assist it.

In the spec file generated when pyinstaller is first run

```py
import site
import os

site_packages = site.getsitepackages()
for site_package in site_packages:
    if "site-packages" in site_package:
        global site_package_path
        site_package_path = site_package
        break

a = Analysis(
    binaries=[(os.path.join(site_package_path, "PySpice", "Config", "logging.yml"), 'PySpice/Config/'),],
)
```